# what does middle guard protection failed %d mean?

Tags: ios7, xcode5

When I build my app to my actual iPhone the debug area shows this:

```
[Allocator] Middle guard protection failed %d
[Allocator] Allocator invalid, falling back to malloc
```

It shows the 2nd line a total of 30 times. I have no idea what it means or how to fix it. It does not show this when I build to the simulator.

I am having issues with getting state preservation to work using storyboards and restoration ID's and I have a feeling this has something to do with a memory issue so it's dumping my memory and therefore I get no app restoration. Basically, when I go back to my app it shows me the last screen I was on for a second and then goes back to the root page.

Anyway, I'd like to fix this malloc stuff so I can at least rule it out the culprit, plus I don't want to have an issue with memory in general...

I've been googling this for a couple of weeks now too and can't find anything!

Comment: do you have xcode 6 installed?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the 2nd beta released last week.

Comment: I had the same issue when I accidentally opened my project on xcode6 beta. Then when I came back to xcode 5 it gives me this warnings. Clear the project on xcode cmd+shift+k, if that does not work, remove the project folder from the simulator folder

Comment: Thanks Andre, so I cleared the Xcode build and it's still giving me the alloc issue. I'm not sure how to do the 2nd step "remove the project folder from the sim folder" though?

Comment: /Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator then look for the version folder and one of the inside number is going to be your app, just go inside and check. Or you can run your project on simulator, the stop it. Go to the simulator and delete the app just like you would do it on iphone.

Comment: I couldn't find the iPhone Simulator folder on my machine so I just deleted the app via the simulator per your 2nd option, then plugged my phone in and built the app on it again and unfortunately, it's still showing the [Allocator] errors :(

Comment: Any clue to what the actual cause is? "Avoid using Xcode 6 beta" is not a solution; I need to test my app against iOS 8...

Comment: agreed, I can't find a specific solution to this. So, I've just started to assume there's actually a problem with how I'm allocating memory. I started searching on how to debug memory issues. Some articles have pointed me towards using Xcodes Developer Tools > Instruments (Xcodes > Open Developer Tools > Instruments). Which seems really powerful and shows all of the app allocations and what not, but I have NO IDEA how to interpret any of the huge amounts of data it spews out. Hopefully I can figure that out soon and that'll be the solution. Otherwise, I'm at a stand still with a 90% done app.

Comment: Im getting this issue as well and can't seem to find any solution for it. Did you ever find the culprit @jammyman34?

Comment: Are you guys using Crashlytics? Commenting the startWithAPIKey solves the problem, so it looks like it's an issue on their end.

Comment: Well, I'll be... @andreamazz that seems to have been the problem! I commented out the startWithAPIKey for Crashlytics in the app delegate file and now I don't seem to get that error. Thank you very much! You should post this in the Answer so i can check it as correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like it's an issue with the Crashlytics framework. I have the same issue, and commenting this API call:

`[Crashlytics startWithAPIKey:API_KEY];`

removes that warning.

Comment: That works indeed. But it also disables Crashlytics completely.

Answer (score 1):

It does indeed seem to be an issue at Crashlytics. I know from other threads that they raised the "Allocator invalid..." issue in relation to another Middle error (not Middle guard protection failed %d), which later got marked as fixed.

I fixed this by deleting all the crashlytics stuff and using the new fabric/crashlytics framework. Problem solved.

(Interestingly, I had it only on an iPad, my iPhone 5C made no complaints at all.)